# Exploring Customers' Buildings

Tags: contractors

I regularly work at different locations, depending on the customer. I like to know my surroundings by exploring the buildings and finding short cuts to point B. As an external contractor, is this acceptable behaviour? I don't walk into random offices, just explore the corridors, stairways, grounds etc.

Comment: I guess you actually tell the customer you're going for a wander, rather than just disappear? Some offices can spot new faces instantly and might get suspicious of some guy/girl randomly walking up and down the corridors.

Comment: Do you do this exploring on your own time?

Comment: Does your job require you to do a lot of walking around the building, or do you mostly just stay at your desk?

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable as long as you're sensitive to cues about where you should and should not go and gracefully accept restrictions. Wandering around is literally how pen-testers make a living. You would be surprised how far a friendly-looking person with a visitor badge can get in most facilities.

Comment: Mostly a desk job, save for a few meetings. I have chronic tendinitis and have to keep the knees loose. Wandering around helps with that.

Comment: @teego1967 is the OP a pen tester?

Comment: I find this question a little hard to answer. If you're on your way to point B, and decide to "explore" a bit by wandering your way there, that's very different than randomly getting up and walking around *just* to explore, which may be seen by some clients as time-wasting if you're doing it frequently. The answer would also pretty clearly depend on the location and nature of the client, and their policies. As a consultant, I've been in buildings where I couldn't leave my desk without an escort, and others where no one cared.

Comment: @dwizum, My point about pen-testers is that they are able to get away with unbelievable stuff in plain sight. The tolerance for folks wandering around, in most orgs, is very high unless you're talking about government facilities with sensitive compartmented security requirements (and even then, they'll just physically prevent you from inadvertently accessing particular areas).

Comment: "`You would be surprised how far a friendly-looking person with a visitor badge can get in most facilities`". Not where I work.  Any employee who sees an unescorted visitor and fails to report it is in deep trouble. And the visitor will, of course, have their badge revoked (before talking to "the authorities"). I suggest that the OP be very aware of what kind of location they are doing this at.

Comment: @teego1967 - I guess my point was that pen testers are *supposed* to feel out the ragged edge of an organization's weaknesses and tolerance for exploitation. If they get caught doing something shady (like wandering aimlessly in an org that doesn't tolerate it), that's just part of the process. If a "normal" employee or contractor gets caught doing something shady, it may result in disciplinary action. Yes, pen testers "get away" with a lot, but that doesn't mean that other staff/visitors should feel okay with trying to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

If you spend a lot of time at the respective customer, AND if your job involves some movement through he building, then it may be OK to "wander".

If not, your behavior might be seen as suspicious. Imagine a repairman finding optimal ways through your apartment. (If needed, imagine a big multi-room apartment, or even a big house.) Would you enjoy finding him everywhere?

As long as there is an obvious way between points A and B, and especially if other employees at that company use this obvious way, you should not explore anything.

It is perfectly fine to explore public places, streets, alleys, parks and forests (if they are available). Just make sure not to get lost, especially in forests :)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on a few things, here's some points I've learned from working at dozens of sites.

- While you *can* go anywhere your badge allows, you shouldn't really wander around.
- **Never tailgate** through a door unless it's a place you are fully expected to be.
- If the company has a campus setting, **exploring the grounds** has never been a problem.
- If the company specifically uses an 'open' plan, walking around usually isn't a problem.
- You can almost always **visit 'open' venues such as cafeterias** in other buildings.
- You can take *different routes* to places you do need to be, like a meeting room.
- I have on occasion taken a "wrong turn" just to take a peek, but always with a nearby destination, like a meeting room.
- If you are friendly with an employee, you can **ask them for a tour**.
- Just ask of you can walk around.  I was someplace last year where they were very proud of some recent renovations and was told, without asking, to check out the 7th and 9th floors because of the artwork.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way: Restrain your movement inside the building, explore outside.

The general (non-restricted) places like cafeteria, relaxing lounge, restrooms, gyms - you are free to visit, do not try to explore the work areas. Most of the restricted places are access-restricted usually, however, if you're not sure better not be involved.

The best way would be to ask one of your colleagues / point-of-contacts in the new office for the directions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you do this in order to improve your efficiency, and as such I don't believe it will be frowned upon.

**The most important thing** is just to ensure that you obtain permission & make it clear to whoever is in charge that you're planning to do some surveying of the surroundings when you get there, in order to move efficiently throughout the premises.

That way you'll be informed if there are any areas they'd prefer you not to access (i.e with meetings going on, sensitive info etc).

Answer (score 1):

Make your manager aware of your intention to do so.

> Hey boss, would it be okay if I did some exploring, I want to make sure I know where everyone and everything is?

And leave it at that.  If they're fine with it, no problem, if not, back down.  It really depends on the security policies of your client.  Always check first.